# How to get the current value of animated values with option useNativeDriver set to true?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-animated

Im trying to get the current value of an `animated.Value` that has the option `useNativeDriver` set to true, but it doesnt work. With others animated values that have same option set to false, it works perfectly.

Comment: Aleksey is right. Would you mark his answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to its value change by:
`this.state.animatedValue.addListener(({value}) => {/* your logic */});`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because, when the useNativeDriver is set to true, the animation no longer runs on the JS thread but goes to the native UI thread, and thus the current animated value is not updated on the JS side as we'd expect it to. This causes abrupt behavior towards the end of the animation cycle.

I figured out a workaround for scenarios like this, where the native driver spoils our offset and gives a jump in our animation towards the end.

Create a pseudo animated value (which will not be used for any animation) and keep updating it alongside your original animated value. Finally when your animation is over (like decay, spring, etc.) set the offsets and current angle with the pseudo value as below:

```
const angle = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current; //original value used in animation; will run on native side
const psuedoAngle = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current; //only to track the value on JS side

//using PanResponder
...
  onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
      angle.setValue(some_value);
      psuedoAngle.setValue(same_value);
  },
  onPanResponderRelease: (evt, {vx, vy}) => {
    // calculate your velocity 
    ...
    const decay1 = Animated.decay(angle,{
        velocity: velocity,
        deceleration: 0.997,
        useNativeDriver: true
      }
    );
    const decay2 = Animated.decay(psuedoAngle,{
        velocity: velocity,
        deceleration: 0.997,
        useNativeDriver: false //this will keep your pseudo value intact
      }
    );

 

   //set offset and current angle in callback as below

Animated.parallel([decay1,decay2]).start(() => {
  psuedoAngle.flattenOffset();
  angle.setOffset(psuedoAngle._value);  //correct value passed to original value
  psuedoAngle.setOffset(psuedoAngle._value);
  angle.setValue(0);
  psuedoAngle.setValue(0);
});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Number.parseFloat(JSON.stringify(animatedValue))
```

Try this will work?

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same problem and using the addListener function didn't really solved it for me. What I did was to create a ref and changing that value inside the callback function in the start() method as follows:

```js
const rotateAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
const previousRotation = useRef(0)

useEffect(() => {

     //@ts-ignore
    //  const currentRotation = rotateAnim.__getValue();  // this only works when useNativeDriver is FALSE, which is not desirable

     let angleDifference = rotation - previousRotation.current; //Here I'm using the current value of the animation before it is animated
     while (angleDifference < -180) angleDifference += 360;
     while (angleDifference > 180) angleDifference -= 360;

     const newRotation = previousRotation.current + angleDifference;
     Animated.timing(rotateAnim, {
          toValue: newRotation,
          duration: 100,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start(()=>{
          previousRotation.current = newRotation
          //Here I assign my current previousNotation value to the current rotation value just after the animation has ended. In this way I can use the current value of the animation before it runs
        });


  }, [rotation])
```

This way, you are ensuring that every time the animated value updates, it is saved in a ref and usable for comparing values differences for example. Hope this helps!